# Failed when trying to create AVD is Android SDK

Tags: android, linux

I am using the 64 bit Ubuntu 11.04 and Eclipse Indigo with the Open JDK and got the following libs

lib32asound2 is already the newest version.
lib32gcc1 is already the newest version.
lib32ncurses5 is already the newest version.
lib32stdc++6 is already the newest version.
lib32z1 is already the newest version.
ia32-libs is already the newest version.

Still when I try to create the Virtual Device in Android SDK I get the following error:

[2011-07-04 21:30:16 - SDK Manager] Failed to create the SD card.
[2011-07-04 21:30:16 - SDK Manager] Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder.

How can i solve this? I googled but unable to get the right solution.

Comment: When I dont allocate the SD card size i am able to create AVD but when tried to launch an application got the following error:

 Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'AVD2.2' is not available. Launching new emulator.
[2011-07-05 09:42:33 - Hello Android] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'AVD2.2'
[2011-07-05 09:42:33 - Hello Android] Launch canceled!

Comment: Please stop flagging this question for help.  After the required waiting period, you can place a bounty on your question.  See the [faq#bounty] for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As this problem is with the write access, finally I found that we have to give read write and execute access for the all users to the following directories:

```
sdk_installation_directory/tools (chmod -R 777 )<br />
home/username/.android/avd (chmod -R 777) <br />
```

** Don't use 'directoryName/*'

** Use Sun JDK

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be due to not installing the i386 libraries required by Android Studio.
You have the libraries installed, but they may be the x64 versions!

Make sure you follow the installation instructions from https://developer.android.com/studio/install.html.

---

Also you may want to read about multiarch on Debian based distros: https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO