# Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder - Mac OSX

Tags: java, android, macos

When I try to create a new android emulator with the AVD Manager I keep getting the error "Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder." no matter what size I set the SD card! Does anyone know why? I'm running Mac OSX 64 Bit

Comment: might be some read/write permission issue try this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6573876/failed-when-trying-to-create-avd-is-android-sdk

Comment: I tried settings the permissions, didn't seem to work.

Comment: Hi William, i'm having the same issue, how did you solve this?

Answer (score 3):

On Android SDK Manager, I deleted Tools/Android SDK Tools, and reinstalled it.

For some reason, everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

Select the appropriate CPU / ABI while creating your AVD. Choose the emulator accelerator that you've installed in your Android SDK. I had installed Intel x86 emulator but kept choosing ARM(armeabi-v7a) during AVD setup.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. I just assigned more internal storage to the emulator and deactivated the creation of the SD card.